# How to define two mode (night/day) for AngularJS Application

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, angular-ui-router

I am working on an application using Angularjs. I am struck with one issues Animations.
I want to add to my application the way that make here be displayed in two mode (night and day mode). i saw that i can use the theme provider to change the theme every time i change the mode. but is there any else solution for this? for example using cascading style sheet and how is it used.
Can any one please help me and suggest the Best way to do this Solution.
Thanks

Comment: You can add `ng-class="{day: mode == 'day', night: mode == 'night'}"` to root element and add different style in your css (or sass) based on the class. and use `$scope.mode = 'day'` or `$scope.mode = 'night'` in controller.

Comment: in this way i should add ng-class on every single element right ? i am looking for something global

Comment: No, you define one global ng-class (added to element that have root ng-controller) and append .day or .night at the beginning of the selectors in you css file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to toggle css class on the *body* element depending on the day/night condition.

```
<body ng-class="{'night-mode': isNight()}">
    <div>
        <p>Some</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>Inside</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

In css you define default theme and the night alternative:

```
body div {
    background-color: gray;
}

body.night-mode div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Inside angularjs controller define function checking night-mode conditions:

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.isNight = function() {
        var hours = new Date().getHours();
        return hours > 19 || hours < 8;
    };    
}
```

That's an example of course ;)

Comment: thanks a lot it is a good solution for the backgroud but the problem that if i want to convert the color text and element in every time i change the mode how that can be done ?

Comment: When we toggle css class of body element we can specify style of every element that's inside. Eg: `body.night-mode p {color: red}` changes font-color of every paragraph inside body during night-mode. All you need is to remember to prepend every style definition with: `body.night-mode`. Is that clear to you?

Comment: Preprocessors like LESS or SASS can be useful in your situation